# Gitlab perma-link by projectId

Tags: gitlab

I would like to save only the project id of a gitlab project and link to it via that. The expectation is that the project name and namespace will change. Is there a way to link to a gitlab project via only its id and have gitlab automatically redirect to the correct url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this closed issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/53671), you are now able to access a project using only project ID via https://gitlab.com/projects/:id

https://gitlab.com/projects/13083 redirects to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce

```
$ curl -v 'https://gitlab.com/projects/13083'
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce
```

I removed a lot of the `curl` output, but left the interesting parts

As pointed out by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc), [this change](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/24467) was included in [GitLab 11.8](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release/tasks/issues/669)

Comment: Does not work for me on 11.7.0. Can you confirm if updating would fix it?

Comment: @Harry It is part of 11.8: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release/tasks/issues/669